# Using mongo updateZoneKeyRange to reduce a zone range

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm trying to update an existing zone's range named `hot` from

`{ "id" : 1507520572 }, { "id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 }`

using

`sh.updateZoneKeyRange('db.collection', { id: 1507520572 }, { id: 9999999999 }, 'hot')`,

but I'm getting the error

`Zone range: { id: 1507520572.0 } -->> { id: 9999999999.0 }  on  hot is overlapping with existing: { id: 1507520572 } -->> { id: MaxKey }  on  hot`.

My plan is to then create a new zone from `9999999999` to `MaxKey`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the previous range first with

`db.runCommand({ updateZoneKeyRange: 'db.collection', min: {id: 1507520572}, max: {id: MaxKey}, zone: null })`,

then it let me create the new ranges.